# How to use same same django_filters.CharFilter field for two separate fields

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-filter, django-tables2

So, basically I have a FilterSet I am using with django-tables2. Now I need to use have a single char field which should search two separate fields from the Model.

For example:

```py
ip_addr = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')
virtual_ip = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')
```

Above is my current FilterSet. Both these are rendered into two separate fields in the Template. But I want to combine them into a single field in the front end, which looks up either in ip_addr OR in virtual_ip.

Can any one point me in right direction.

Answer (score 3):

You can create complex lookups with Q objects inside a custom method for filtering more than one field, like this:

```
from django.db.models import Q
# ..your other imports..

YouFilterSet(django_filters.FilterSet):
    # ip_addr = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')
    # virtual_ip = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')
    my_lookup_field = django_filters.CharFilter(label='ip', method='my_lookup_method')

    class Meta:
        # ..your meta attributes..

    def my_lookup_method(self, queryset, name, value):
        return queryset.filter(Q(ip_addr__icontains=value)|Q(virtual_ip__icontains=value))
```

This will return a `Queryset` with your value in either your ip_addr or virtual_ip fields. For more info you can check the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) for Q objects and also [here](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/usage.html#customize-filtering-with-filter-method) and [here](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/ref/filters.html#method) for custom methods in Filters.